# React Router V4 callback when finished unmounting page component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am looking for a way of transitioning between pages with React Router V4.

Specifically, I am looking for a way to 1) prevent triggering the navigation to the new page when clicking the `Link` component; 2) then, start animating out the current page, and when animation is finished and the component is ready to be unmounted, unmount and trigger `history.navigate` or `history.push`.

Is there a common way to do this, or something similar to animate between pages with React Router V4?

Thanks!

EDIT: as @Tholle points out pages can be transitioned using CSSTransitions, as in https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/animated-transitions. I know that, and I've read many articles on different ways of doing it. The most common strategy is to overlap both the current and incoming pages in a fixed position, with the latter in `opacity: 0`, and transition between them with CSS using the timings provided by the CSS transition component. But the lack of control over the life circle of the components surprise me, so I'm looking for a way to transition between pages with better control over the life circle of the page components: componentWillMount, componentDidMount, componentWillUnmount and componentDidUnmount.

Comment: Have you seen [this part](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/animated-transitions) of the documentation?

Comment: Yes, and many other tutorials/articles/docs: the strategy for transitioning pages using CSSTransition component is overlaping the current page with the incoming one in absolute or fixed position, no use of callbacks and no control over the life cicle of the route components.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Have you stumbled upon [this one](https://hackernoon.com/animated-page-transitions-with-react-router-4-reacttransitiongroup-and-animated-1ca17bd97a1a)? The use of `componentWillAppear`, `componentWillEnter`,  and `componentWillLeave` might be what you need.

Comment: Yes, did read it and implemented my own version as well; but it uses the same strategy, with position absolute: look for the most highlighted part of the article.

Comment: I'm not sure what position absolute has to do with your question. You can use react transitions in the given example to add/remove any class with any given styles that you want. If you want it to slide right you can, if you want your page to bounce before leaving you can do that too. Also once a component is unmounted it's gone. You can only perform logic in the componentWillUnmount life cycle method.

Comment: I'll be more explicit: how can you trigger a method just before current page componentWIllUnmount, but before new componentWillMount? With CSSTransitions you can't, because new page is rendered over old one.

Comment: Hi, @antoniodcorrea, I am looking to achieve (1), have you find how?

Comment: Hi @DimitriKopriwa: No, I didn't find a way to control when navigation is triggered in `<Link />` component. If you have `history` available in your component you can make use of `props.history.push('/url')` instead. Anyway, I'm still curious about how to trigger actions with click on `<Link />` and navigating after action finished, but probably this would not be a declarative approach —and a declarative approach is mandatory in React—.